# PHP mail function can't send out email when I added .com.sg instead of just .com

Tags: php, function, email

I want to send out a link for user to verify their account after they register. But when I use `www.singapore.com` at the `$message` I am able to receive the email, but when I change it back to `www.singapore.com.sg` I can't receive it. I wonder is it because of the link or there is some error in my codes? Please help me.

```
$domain ='www.singapore.com'; 
$id = mysql_insert_id(); 
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
$subject = "E-mail Verification"; 
$message = 'Click on the link to verify your account: http://'.$domain.'/rates/activation.php?id='.$id.' '; 
$headers = "From: <Singapore> \r\n"; 
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers, '-f enquiry@singapore.com.sg');
```

Comment: Is it returning any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the -f envelope option?    If memory serves, any address put in there needs to be already added as a trusted user in the sendmail configuration.

I found this on the PHP mail docs:

> The user that the webserver runs as should be added as a trusted user
>   to the sendmail configuration to prevent a 'X-Warning' header from
>   being added to the message when the envelope sender (-f) is set using
>   this method. For sendmail users, this file is /etc/mail/trusted-users.

Are you simply trying to set the reply to and from addresses? If so, use the $header for that and don't bother with the additional parameters.

```
$headers = “From: enquiry@singapore.com.sg” . “\r\n” . “Reply-To: enquiry@singapore.com.sg”;
```

Comment: I want to add the activation link in the $message. But when I add .sg behide the $domain, the user can't receive my email.

Comment: Please take a look at the PHP mail function so that you'll understand better.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your code. Change it to this

```
$message = 'Click on the link to verify your account: http://'.$domain.'/rates/activation.php?id='.$id;
```

It has extra quotes at the last.

Hope that helps.. :)

Comment: still can't send it with .sg in the link... :(

Comment: There must be something wrong with your code because $message is just a string. It doesn't affect anything if its .com.sg or just .com. Try reading php manual for proper usage of the mail function. It's best to find out what the error is. You can check your error log. It's easy to fix when you know what the error is.