# PHP mail function user can't receive the mail if I added .com.sg instead of just .com

Tags: php, email, verification, email-verification

I want to send the user an activation link after they registered an account. when I put this http://www.homeloan.com.sg in the $message I didn't receive the email, but when I remove the .sg and put http://www.homeloan.com it works. There's no error message, so I really don't know what's my mistake. Please help

**here are my codes:**

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = "E-mail Verification";
$message = 'Click on the link to verify your account-> http://www.homeloan.com.sg/rates/activate?id='.$id.'';
$headers = "From: Homeloan Singapore" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: enquiry@homeloan.com.sg"; 
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers, '-f enquiry@homeloan.com.sg');
```

Comment: i would suspect the recipients spam filters are at fault.

Comment: It is quite unlikely .sg is causing the problem. Would you have another e-mail with a .sg domain to test this out?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: @Dagon I found the mail in my hotmail junk folder. When I use my gmail account, I can't receive the mail.

Comment: @jco yes, there's no error at the error logs.

Comment: @Marcel Tjandraatmadja I tested google.com.sg and it work, but when I change it back to homeloan.com.sg it doesn't work

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255128/php-mail-function-cant-send-out-email-when-i-added-com-sg-instead-of-just-com , please do not ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if your site have a form to fill, then fill the form correctly by assembling the input tag in the corresponded variable.

Try concatenating 'the email' to the variables ($...) with (.) or "...".

Comment: Also the last sentence would be better organized by separating the variables with the commas, such as: 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f enquiry@homeloan.com.sg');

Try this:
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers . '-f enquiry@homeloan.com.sg');

Difference? the concatenation (.) instead of the comma (,)

your code:
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers, '-f enquiry@homeloan.com.sg');

try this one:
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers . '-f enquiry@homeloan.com.sg');

Answer (score 0):

> I really don't know what's my mistake

There is no mistake. I tried this code:

```
<?php
$id = 1;
$to = 'my_email@gmail.com';
$subject = "E-mail Verification";
$message = 'Click on the link to verify your account-> http://www.homeloan.com.sg/rates/activate?id='.$id;
$headers = "From: Homeloan Singapore" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: enquiry@homeloan.com.sg";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers, '-f enquiry@homeloan.com.sg');
```

It arrived in the mailbox. Maybe, for your account it was put into spam folder?

Comment: may I know what type of account u are using? e.g yahoo, gmail or hotmail?

Comment: gmail. I had the opposite case to PSY: without .sg was put to spam. With .sg - to the inbox.